# Babel Config "strict mode"

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

For some strange reason I can't for the life of me compile "vendor" libraries with my build process.

Im getting this error:  `SyntaxError: <FILENAME> 'with' in strict mode`.

> (where `<FILENAME>` is an actual existing filename)

The line that's failing is `> 130928 | with (locals || {}) { (function(){`
 and its complaining about that `with`. Bear in mind that this file is outside my control.

My `.babelrc` file has this config.

```
{
    "compact": true,
    "plugins": [
        "transform-runtime",
        "undeclared-variables-check"
    ],
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "stage-0"
    ]
}
```

I'm using babel 6, I know the general conscious is to use version 5, but no luck there either.

Comment: Why do you run ES5 code through babel at very first place?

Comment: The "sexy" minification and optimizations it offers. Above Google's closure compiler, or uglify. I know it works, because my React apps i've read through the compiled code, and it makes more sense than uglify.

Comment: Babel does not minify/optimise.

Comment: Reference to what does not exist? Sorry, I cannot get a link to a page that does not exist.

Comment: I know it does optimization, and does it well. Figurative speaking, it tightens up the code. WIth all its transformers and alike.

Comment: It does not. Babel produces code that is at least as short as it was (if it does not perform any transformation at all). If any transformation was applied - the code becomes longer. Prove me wrong.

Comment: Could you provide an example of an meaningful optimization it performs? I see [a few very minor optional minification plugins](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#minification), but I'm not aware of it doing anything like uglify or closure.

Comment: *"my React apps i've read through the compiled code, and it makes more sense than uglify"* We might be talking past each other (different meaning of "optimized"?), because well-optimized code is generally expected to make *less* sense than less-optimized code.

Comment: Just gives me a toolset of things to make my life easier, ie [Undefined->Void](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-undefined-to-void/)..

Comment: Why would you use that instead of uglifyjs2? This whole discussion makes no sense.

Comment: Irrespective of this - we can move this discussion to Reddit. But to get down to the point, how do I get it working..?

Comment: To get it working - you don't pass ES5 code through babel. To minify - you use tools designed to minify. Babel is not one of them.

Comment: @zerkms - Would you mind making that the answer to this question, and ill resolve it.

Comment: @zerkms - With that, what tools do you use for minification / optimization?

Comment: uglifyjs2 ..........

Comment: Voted to close this question: there is no question, only statements. It's not clear what the expected and actual results are or whether the observed behavior should be explained. The comments do not help clarifying either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this hasn't been answered already.

The es2015 preset (and, to my understanding, every babel preset) enables strict mode.  Check out [MDN's article on strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), specifically the section with header "Simplifying variable uses".  `with` is illegal in strict mode.