# Babel 6 react JSX transformer - disable strict

Tags: javascript, babeljs, reactjs

#### Issue

I'm using babel 6 for react JSX transforms. However I'm not using the react preset, I am ONLY using the 'transform-react-jsx' plugin (and trying strict-mode disable option), here is my .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-react-jsx"]
  ],
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "strictMode": false
}
```

However I have required a thirdparty javascript that uses 'with' (out of my control) which emits following error:
[SyntaxError: foo.js: 'with' in strict mode .. ]

So I need to disable strict mode, This is same problem as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778980/babel-config-strict-mode) however I am NOT using es6/es2015 stuff, only jsx transforms.

With babel 6 there is no blacklist and I've only specified ONE plugin, so I'm suspect there is no way to disable.

Comment: If that's all you've got as your config, Babel isn't the one inserting `use strict`, it must be something else. Are you sure that is the only Babel config you have? You've not passing some as arguments somewhere or something?

Comment: @loganfsmyth it's the only one. I will try to reproduce on command line without any other steps

Comment: if it's helpful, using a reactify transform instead works without issue.

Comment: I found [transform-strict-mode](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode) , however it had no effect

Comment: The `strict-mode` transform adds `use strict`, if you don't have it, it won't add it. It is normally part of `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`

Comment: then why does the example provided have a strict option? It didnt work anyway so I am inclined to believe you :) I am suspect react-jsx transform pulls in a dep that re-enables it somewhere

Comment: Because that flag is for ES6 specification strictness, not JS strict mode.

Comment: Well then, I'm in hell

Comment: If that third party script uses `with`, it's clearly not designed to be used as a module. Leave it out of your bundler's build, and specifically request it with a `<script>` tag.

Comment: That is what we ended up doing after finding and shooting all imports

Answer (score 1):

According to [this line](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/4c371132ae7321f6d08567eab54a59049e07f246/lib/parser.js#L2), the `strictMode` option is indeed parsed.

I don't understand the syntax you used for your [.babelrc](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/), though. Why an array?

Try this:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-react-jsx"]
  ],
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "strictMode": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited answer to reflect your feedback. It however still does not work

Comment: There are several moving parts (webpack, babel in a different project, etc..) so I am working to simplify the issue

Answer (score 0):

[transform-strict-mode](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-strict-mode/) is used only to include the strict mode not to disable it. So setting it to false `["transform-strict-mode", {"strict": false}]` will change nothing, in your case better remove this plug-in then including it.
But if somewhere else you are using a plugin or preset that includes the strict mode, try maybe to use [es2015-loose](https://github.com/bkonkle/babel-preset-es2015-loose) :

1. install

   `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015-loose babel-preset-es2015`
2. config

   `{"presets": ["es2015-loose"]}`

Comment: I am using no other plugins or presets, just transform-react-jsx. I guess it may pull something else in. I will update question to reflect what I'm trying