# How to disable strict mode in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an external JS file which I want to import as a module in my React native app. The external module is not in strict mode.
While running the app, the modules are converted to strict mode and I'm getting the error as shown in the screenshot below.

How can I disable the strict mode transformation of the modules located in the directory `./lib/js/socialcalc`.

I have studied the following links:

- [React Native: SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230872/react-native-syntaxerror-strict-mode-does-not-allow-function-declarations-in-a)
- [Babel 6 react JSX transformer - disable strict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756673/babel-6-react-jsx-transformer-disable-strict)
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5316
- http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-strict-mode/

My external JS file :

```
var SocialCalc = require("./socialcalc/SocialCalc.js");

export function initializeApp(){
    alert("Initializing...");
}
```

Note: `SocialCalc.js` is the file which I wish to ignore while transforming to strict mode.

[image: Screenshot of the simulator]

Comment: I'm not sure how to disable specific error messages, but you can disable React redbox like this "console.reportErrorsAsExceptions = false;"

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1e8f3b11027fe0a7514b4fc97d0798d3c64bc895/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js#L97