# How to disable react strict mode on third party libraries

Tags: reactjs, react-strictmode

We use strict mode in our React app. But third parties does not use strict mode. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post code samples of what you have done (i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: Possible related question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756673/babel-6-react-jsx-transformer-disable-strict

Comment: I doubt this can be done. Ignore messages that are related to third-party components.

Comment: React can’t detect which components are “third party”

Answer (score 1):

In `index.js` file remove the `React.StrictMode` wrapper.

From this

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

To this

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: This is an old question, so I doubt we'll get clarification from the asker, but I think they were trying to only disable strict mode for third party components, not their entire app.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably not disable strict mode for third party libraries only, but you can apply strict mode to only a subset of your own code. If the non-strict third party libraries are only used in specific parts of the app, the rest of the app can be in strict mode.

Here is an example:

```
<div>
  <div>
    Non-strict code containing third party libraries
  </div>
  <React.StrictMode>
    <div>
      Strict code here
    </div>
  </React.StrictMode>
</div>
```

If the third party libraries are used in a lot of places, this will be more problematic.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you can provide any code of your application where you used StrictMode. I think this is possible. but the issue is where you used StrictMode. You must use it globally to achieve StrictMode for all components and libraries. And it's better if you can mention which third part library that StrictMode is not working.

```
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Like in this code try to use it by wrapping for the main app component. And also there may be some restrictions for the third-party library use have used. Please check it our.

Answer (score -3):

In React, the Strict Mode is a development mode feature that helps identify potential problems in an application by enabling additional checks and warnings. However, third-party libraries may not be designed to work with Strict Mode and could throw warnings or cause issues when used together.

To disable React Strict Mode for third-party libraries while keeping it enabled for your app, you can wrap the third-party components or parts of your code that interact with the third-party library inside a component that doesn't use Strict Mode.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
    // App.js
import React from 'react';
import ThirdPartyComponent from 'third-party-library'; // Example import for a third-party component
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

function ThirdPartyWrapper() {
  return <ThirdPartyComponent />;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <MyComponent />
      <ThirdPartyWrapper />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In this example, the ThirdPartyWrapper component is outside of the React.StrictMode component, so any third-party components rendered inside it will not be affected by Strict Mode checks. However, the rest of your application, including your MyComponent, will still run in Strict Mode, allowing you to catch any potential issues in your own code.

Remember that disabling Strict Mode for third-party libraries means you won't get the extra checks and warnings that Strict Mode provides, so use this approach cautiously and make sure the third-party library you're using is stable and doesn't introduce any unexpected side effects when used without Strict Mode. If possible, always try to use third-party libraries that are designed to work well in a React Strict Mode environment.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT